# Help with Tests for Apex Class for User Profile Picture

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I came up with an Apex Class to extract the User Profile Picture, to be used in a VisualForce Email Template :

```
public class UserProfilePicture {
    public String profileImageUrl { get; set; }
    List<user> lstuser;


    public UserProfilePicture () {
         lstuser = [select FullPhotoUrl from User where Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
         profileImageUrl=lstuser[0].FullPhotoUrl; 
    }
}
```

Can anyone please assist with a test for this class?

Thank you, 
Ido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really just need to test if the URL is populated, something like this:

```
@isTest static void test() {
    UserProfilePicture upp = new UserProfilePicture();
    System.assert(upp.profileImageUrl <> null);
}
```